# Facebook Graph Api posting on friends wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a problem when trying to post a link to a friends wall using the Facebook graph from my application.
I am currently using the Facebook SDK for PHP, I have no problems posting to the wall of the user that's logged in but cannot post to friends of the logged in user.
I have requested the extended permission "publish_stream" and here is the code am I using:

```
$args = array('message' => $message,
                            'link' => 'google.com',
                            'name' => 'Test!',
                            'caption' => 'Please click on the link',
                            'description' => 'description');
$result = $facebook->api("/$friendId/feed", 'POST', $args );
```

$friendId has the facebook id of the friend of the logged in user, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? Did you read that https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/ (in the bottom there is info about removing ability to posting to friend wall).

Comment: I don't get any error. $result has an array with the id of the post but nothing is posted on the friends wall and the ID does not exist if you go to facebook.com/ID
After reading the blog post does that mean I cannot post to a friends wall using the API anymore do I have to use the feed dialog?

Comment: You will have to, after February 6, 2013. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013 So maybe best not to try and build an app with that functionality anymore anyway.

Answer (score -1):

A quick scan of [the FB API reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) shows that you can set the `to` key value pair in this operation to

> mention or target a user in this post

Comment: No, `to` is a field you that you will get back when _reading_ such a post from the API. Tagging in POSTs made via the API is not possible any more (has been once, but that’s been ages ago). And besides that, I can’t see how this answers the question.